# What's wrong with this data retrieval code?

Tags: sql, spring, jakarta-ee, callback, jdbctemplate

I am new at Java EE and have written a piece of code to populate a List. But while debugging I have found that the Callback function is not getting executed and no data is being retrieved. Please Help.

```
public List<VDRNote> getStdVDRNotes()
{
     final List<VDRNote> notes=new ArrayList<VDRNote>();
     String sql="Select NOTE_ID, NOTES from DCTM_VDR_STD_NOTES ORDER BY NOTE_ID ASC";
         RowCallbackHandler rch1=new RowCallbackHandler() {
             public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
             {
                 VDRNote note=new VDRNote();
                 note.setNoteId(rs.getInt("NOTE_ID"));
                 note.setNote(rs.getString("NOTES"));
                 notes.add(note);
             }};
         jdbcTemplate.query(sql,rch1);
         return notes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks basically ok. Are you sure that the jdbcTemplate.query() gets executed?
Make sure that there are rows in the table, otherwise the processRow() will not get executed.
Also using `queryForList` ([API docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)), it's nicer to read.